# What is the third quantization and the creation and annihilation operators of universes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, beyond-the-standard-model, quantization

We have only recently begun to undergo secondary quantization, and I know that for the introduction of the creation and annihilation operators, the existence of interacting quantum fields is necessary, the interaction of which leads to the processes of creation and annihilation.

Recently I came across an article: ["Third quantization: Modeling the universe as a 'particle' in a quantum field theory of the minisuperspace"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.6369) by Robles-Pérez. It talks about the third quantization and implementation of "operators of creation and annihilation of universes." How to understand the action of these operators? What, in this understanding, leads to the creation and annihilation of universes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions says that third-quantized are fields that create and annihilate second quantized fields. However, there is no a general formalism for third quantized fields established at the level of rigor and applicability as the usual theory of 'second quantized' fields.

A great example that beautifully encodes the virtues and challenges of the formalism is actually string field theory; for an understanding of this analogy in the realm of quantum cosmology, see ['Baby universes, third quantization and the cosmological constant'](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321389903532). The idea is that, even though the 'first quantized' usual strings are on-shell excitations of a second quantized fields, one can tought in the same situation from the worldsheet perspective where the worldsheet  CFT is a second quantized theory and a string field can be identified as a 'third quantized' field in the sense that the creation of a usual string actually creates its worldsheet CFT (a second quantized field).

Concerning the potential applications of this formalism to quantum cosmology: One of the main problems of defining a gravitational path integral for a baby universe concerns the field space over one should integrate. The usual work hypothesis says that one can assume that spherically symmetric universes dominate the path integral (at least in the mini-superspace approximation); notice that this hypothesis is automatically satisfied in string field theory as consequence of the perturbative genus-expansion of string theory. On the side of difficulties one can found the fact that it is not obvious how to take non-perturbative effects into account or even the precise identification of a regime in quantum cosmology where 'third quantized fields' can be correctly described by a weakly coupled theory.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When calculating the path integral for an ordinary quantum particle, integration is carried out over space-time. Over what physical space is the path integral integrated for newborn universes? In the space-time of the mother universe?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress That's a very good question. This is a problem of the 'third quantized approach' as far as I know. I only know about examples where people assume the existence of a parent universe and then compute 'quantum corrections' to its Wheeler-De Witt wavefunction, typically by summing over all possible changes in topology (= baby universes) of the parent universe. I don't know if it there is an example of a background independent third quantized theory. So yes, as far as my Ignorance can tell, all the examples integrate over the possible topologies of the parent universe.

Comment: An example of a background-independent third quantization can be the birth of a universe "from nothing". But this is too speculative. Thank you for answers!

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress It was a pleasure!

Comment: May I ask a little clarifying question? At high energies do gravitons interact with matter and with each other?

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress Well, it depends on the theory of gravity you are considering. In string theory (the leader candidate to describe the quantum nature of gravity) gravitons interact stronger and stronger among them if you use higher energies to scatter them; this is in agreement with all we now about the semi-classical approximation to quantum gravity, that's the orthodox viewpoint.

Comment: @ArmanArmenpress However, there are other candidate theories that propose sort of "asymptotic freedom" (more precisely [asymptotic safety](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_safety_in_quantum_gravity)) for the high energy limit of quantum gravity.[Hořava gravity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.06809) is the prototypical example.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That is, in asymptotically safe theories, the coupling constant with increasing energy either tends to zero asymptotically, or to a finite value. But it does not become exactly zero. Probably there are no models with exactly zero coupling of high energies, and their existence is meaningless. The function cannot just break off))))